# Parent Element of CSS Dropdown Menu Loses Hover Effect When Moving to Menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

The title is wordy and sort of hard to understand but the idea is I have a drop down menu, when the main links that produce the dropdown menu are hover over, their background color and text color change and the menu appears. The problem is, when you move the cursor onto the menu to click the links that just appeared, the hover effect goes away for the main links above. The menu stays and works just fine but I would ideally like the link that produces the menu on hover to keep it's hover effects while the menu is up.

Here is the code of what I'm talking about...

CSS

```
a {
  color: #1EAEDB; }
a:hover {
  color: #0FA0CE; }

.upper-navigation {
  color: #D5D7D5;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  width: 160px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
  padding-left: 24px;
}
.upper-navigation:hover {
  background-color: #232a2d;
}

.lower-navigation {
  color: #4E6875;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.01rem;
  margin-left: 24px;
}

.lower-navigation.s {
  color: #D5D7D5;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  background-color: #232a2d;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0px 24px 18px 0px;
  width: 160px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/" class="upper-navigation">Homepage</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="upper-navigation">Community</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/" class="lower-navigation s">First Link</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="/" class="lower-navigation s">Second Link</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="/" class="lower-navigation s">Third Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/" class="upper-navigation">Discover</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/" class="lower-navigation s">First Link</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="/" class="lower-navigation s">Second Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a fiddle of the code in action...

https://jsfiddle.net/zgoewybm/1/

Ideally, when over the menu, the Ipsum and Dolor links should keep the dark background and the light blue text color.

edit: I've solved the problem myself. For anyone curious, I added this to the HTML...

```
.upper-navigation:hover, li:hover {
  background-color: #232a2d;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #0FA0CE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply added this to the HTML...

```
.upper-navigation:hover, li:hover {
  background-color: #232a2d;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #0FA0CE;
}
```